# Bind Laravel table to other database connection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am finding some difficulties to bind one relationship table to my second database.

In "db_main" I have tables, with the basic details about each object and than I have other tables: "db_site1", "db_site2" etc, in which tables I save detailed information about the same objects.

Everything is working find with that schema, except one situation in that I have relationship table (bookmaker_games), which must be only on "db_main". The table save the relations between bookmakers and games.

On my website1 I want to list the games of a bookmaker with the following models:

```
class Bookmaker extends Model {

    public function games() {
        // here the database is "db_site1"
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Game', 'bookmaker_games', 'bookmaker_id', 'game_id');

    }

}

class Game extends Model {

    public function bookmakers() {
        // here the database is "db_site1"
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Bookmaker', 'bookmaker_games', 'game_id', 'bookmaker_id');

    }
}

class BookmakerGame extends Model {

    protected $connection = 'db_main';

}
```

When I try to return all games, it is thinking that "bookmaker_games"-table is on database "db_site1", which is wrong.

What is the best way to tell that relationship to look at the correct database ?

Comment: the class `BookmakerGame` should extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot`

Comment: i have tried, but still get the same error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_site1.bookmaker_games' doesn't exis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `BookmakerGame` as a subclass of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot`

Then define the relationships to use it.

**Prefixing the connection name**

```php
//...
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Bookmaker extends Model {

    public function games() {
        // here the database is "db_site1"
        return $this->belongsToMany(
           'App\Models\Game', 'db_main.bookmaker_games', 'bookmaker_id', 'game_id')
            ->using('App\Models\BookmakerGame');
    }
}

class Game extends Model {

    public function bookmakers() {
        // here the database is "db_site1"
        return $this->belongsToMany(
           'App\Models\Bookmaker', 'db_main.bookmaker_games', 'game_id', 'bookmaker_id')
            ->using('App\Models\BookmakerGame');

    }
}

class BookmakerGame extends Pivot {
    protected $connection = 'db_main';
}
```

**Using the class path to the pivot**

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Bookmaker extends Model {

    public function games() {
        // here the database is "db_site1"
        return $this->belongsToMany(
           'App\Models\Game', 'App\Models\BookmakerGame', 'bookmaker_id', 'game_id');
    }
}

class Game extends Model {

    public function bookmakers() {
        // here the database is "db_site1"
        return $this->belongsToMany(
           'App\Models\Bookmaker', 'App\Models\BookmakerGame', 'game_id', 'bookmaker_id');

    }
}

class BookmakerGame extends Pivot {
    protected $connection = 'db_main';
    protected $table = 'bookmaker_games';
}
```

Comment: Still does not work. The BookmakerGame is still not searching in the right datbase :(

Comment: I suggest to prefix the connection name to the table or use the class path to the `BookmakerGame`